# How can I set the path for IOFactory.php of PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

Below is the my localhost directory sturcture-
 
htdocs\software\office_admin\exam_excel\Classes\PHPExcel.php
htdocs\software\office_admin\exam_excel\Classes\PHPExcel\IOFactory.php
htdocs\software\office_admin\includes\classes\myownclassfiles.php
htdocs\software\office_admin\includes\example.inc.php

When I use IOFactory.php in example.inc.php using

```
require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';<br>
require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
```

I am getting list of warnings here are 2-3 samples-

> Warning:
>   include_once(includes/classes/class.PHPExcel_Shared_String.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\manazeschool\software\office_admin\index.php on line
>   26
>
> Warning: include_once(): Failed opening
>   'includes/classes/class.PHPExcel_Shared_String.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\manazeschool\software\office_admin\index.php on line
>   26
>
> Warning:
>   include_once(includes/classes/class.PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\manazeschool\software\office_admin\index.php on line
>   26
>
> Warning: include_once(): Failed opening
>   'includes/classes/class.PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\manazeschool\software\office_admin\index.php on line
>   26

My own customized class path settings-

```
if (!defined("INCLUDES_CLASS_PATH")) {
    define("INCLUDES_CLASS_PATH", "includes/classes");
}

$path_arr = explode('/', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
$cur_foldpath =  count($path_arr)-3;
//This variable is for avoiding the unautherized page access 

if (!defined('FROMINDEX')) {    
   define('FROMINDEX', true);
}
if (!defined('DS')) {
   define('DS', '/');
}   
include_once('includes/config.inc.php');
   //class
   function __autoload($class_name) {
    include_once INCLUDES_CLASS_PATH . DS . "class." . $class_name . '.php';
   }    
   include (INCLUDES_CLASS_PATH . DS .'developer.mysql.class.php');
   include (INCLUDES_CLASS_PATH . DS . 'validation.class.php');
   include (INCLUDES_CLASS_PATH . DS . 'html_form.class.php');
   //files
   include (INCLUDES_PATH . DS .'messages.inc.php');
   include (INCLUDES_PATH . DS . 'functions.inc.php');
.....
}
```

How can I overcome from these warning

Answer (score 0):

PHPExcel provides its own SPL-compliant autoloader; register your own autoloader with [spl_autoload_register()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php), and the two should work together - see section 3.2, entitled "Lazy Loader", in the developer documentation for details

**EDIT**

If you modify your own autoloader to test for the existence of the classfile before including it (using file_exists()) and return false if it doesn't exist (only including it if it does exist), then that should work

```
function myAutoload($class_name) { 
    if (!file_exists(INCLUDES_CLASS_PATH . DS . "class." . $class_name . '.php')) { 
        return false; 
    } 
    include_once INCLUDES_CLASS_PATH . DS . "class." . $class_name . '.php'; 
} 

 spl_autoload_register('myAutoload');
```

Then make sure that your include for `Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php` is looking in the right directory to actually find the file. The PHPExcel IOFactory will register the PHPExcel autoloader with SPL.

When a class is requested for autoload, SPL should handle checking using your autoloader first, which will return a `false` for PHPExcel classes (and any other classes that can't be found); then SPL should call the PHPExcel autoloader, which will load any PHPExcel classes.

Comment: I changed as per documentation previous - `function __autoload($class_name) {
 include_once INCLUDES_CLASS_PATH . DS . "class." . $class_name . '.php';
 }` Changed to `function myAutoload($class_name) {
  include_once INCLUDES_CLASS_PATH . DS . "class." . $class_name . '.php';
 }spl_autoload_register('myAutoload');` But still getting same numbers of warnings

Comment: So is your autoload function called `myAutoload`?

Comment: Yes as per documentation I changed and kept same name.

Comment: Because I note that your code snippet in the comment above still uses `function __autoload($class_name){...}`

Comment: No I mentioned my previous code which I changed to this code - `function myAutoload($class_name) { include_once INCLUDES_CLASS_PATH . DS . "class." . $class_name . '.php'; }spl_autoload_register('myAutoload');`

Comment: In that case, I have absolutely no idea whatsoever why spl_autoload_register is failing to work correctly

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47459/discussion-between-user3100533-and-mark-baker)